# start map_server with custom frame_id

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently use

```
rosrun map_server map_server testenvironment.yaml
```

to run the map server. It uses "map" as frame_id. I want it to set "odometry_link" as frame id. The documentation says something about a parameter ~frame_id, but it does not say how to use it. Can anyone give an example of how to start the map_server with a custom frame id?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198590/start-map_server-with-custom-frame_id/) by [jjoller](https://answers.ros.org/users/20985/jjoller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can pass frame_id param from command line

```
rosrun map_server map_server testenvironment.yaml _frame_id:="odometry_link"
```

thanks to http://streebgreebling.blogspot.de/2010/04/passing-command-line-parameters-to.html

---

*Update:*

passing param in `.launch` file

```
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="testenvironment.yaml">
<param name="frame_id" value="odometry_link" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjoller](https://answers.ros.org/users/20985/jjoller/) on 2014-12-18**:
Thanks that helped a lot, I would have never guessed that. How to do the same thing using a map file?

<node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="the_map" args="$(arg map_name) _frame_id:="odometry_link" />

?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-18**:
i think you mean launch in launch file, i had updated the answer.